# Here traffic api - How can I restrict my query to only return data for a particular type of roadway?

Tags: here-api

I'm using the here traffic api to obtain information about congestions for different roadways in Germany.
How can I restrict the API to only return traffic items of a particular kind of highway (like Autobahn highways), excluding more local highway types like state roads or city streets?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by functional class. Autobahn should be FC 1, maybe some FC 2. Just check a few places you're interested in.

Here's an API call to give you FC 1 and FC 2:
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?prox=52.50465004078383,13.274000549316355,1000&maxfunctionalclass=2&responseattributes=sh,fc&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

And some links to the documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/flow.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/resource-parameters-flow.html#resource-parameters-flow__max-functional-class